# Setting nosignal option for CURL command line?

Tags: unix, curl

From the libcurl documentation, I understand NOSIGNAL has to be set to 1 when using multi-thread program.

However, if I am calling curl from a command line, I don't see a NOSIGNAL switch/option. How do I set nosignal when calling curl directly?

Comment: Why would you need to set `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` for the `curl` command line utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't: as you said, there is no such option documented by cURL help (and you can also verify that there is no reference to `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` within the command-line source code - see `src/tool_operate.c`).

*Now the question is why you would need this, as asked by Celada. Using libcurl in a multi-threaded context makes sense (i.e. you may want to create/reuse curl handles from several threads) - and you should then follow the [best practices](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html#Multi-threading), but I don't see the point with the CLI tool.*